# Solve::units: Solve was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input

Tags: equation-solving, subscript

I'd like to solve the following two equations for P. But I'm getting "Solve was unable to determine the units of quantities that appear in the input.". Any suggestions on what could be the cause for this?

```
Clear["Global`*"] ;
Solve[{T^4 == ((1 - A) (1 - P) Subscript[R, s]^2 Subscript[T, 
    eff]^4)/(2 a^2), Subscript[\[CapitalDelta]F, SE]/F == (\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(R\), \(p\), \(2\)]\ *\ 
\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(day\)]\))/(
   Subscript[R, s ]* Subscript[T, eff])}, {P, Subscript[T, 
  eff]}, Reals]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the use of subscripted variables, they cause more trouble than they're worth. Use [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html) to display variables in any manner desired.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[Tday] = Subscript["T", "day"];
Format[Teff] = Subscript["T", "eff"];
Format[Rs] = Subscript["R", "s"];
Format[Rp] = Subscript["R", "p"];
Format[ΔFse] = Subscript["ΔF", "SE"];

eqns = {T^4 == ((1 - A) (1 - P) Rs^2 Teff^4)/(2 a^2),
  ΔFse/F == (Rp^2 * Tday)/(Rs* Teff)}
```

[image]

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) will then work

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {P, Teff}, Reals] // Simplify
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqns /. sol[[1]] // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: excellent answer, solves also the issue with the subscripts. thanks